# Extract digits with regular expression in BASH

Tags: regex, bash

I have a script that runs a command like
`$exiftool 3PDki5ZyhBgnoTEUu4JP.mov|grep -m1 Duration` 
and depending on the files I get back results like these

```
Duration                        : 01:25  
Duration                        01:25  
Duration                        01.25
```

I would like to be able to extract from these strings only the time, that is, *01:25* or *1.25*.

Comment: AWK <3 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
....|grep -o "[^ ]*$"
```

or this short one:

```
...|awk '$0=$NF'
```

Comment: @AlexFlo forgot mentioning, if there were trailing spaces on line the `grep` won't work, take the awk one. or this grep: `...|grep -oP '[^ ]*(?= *)$'`

Comment: I like the AWK example better :-) I even started reading a tutorial on AWK, it is indeed powerful and useful. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexFlo yep, I think awk, sed and grep are tools for lazy man (like me). when one knows these three tools, 95% text processing could be done. :) (I am lazy and don't want to memorize those different options of cut, join, paste, pr, seq, comm....) :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. The awk takes just the last column after a space and I've added the tr in case you want to be really perfectionist and have only hh:mm format (and not hh.mm)

```
exiftool 3PDki5ZyhBgnoTEUu4JP.mov|grep -m1 Duration | awk '{ print $NF }' | tr '.' ':'
```